# IIS Application The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid

Tags: f#, asp.net-core-webapi

I am running a .Net 6.0 Web API application that works fine on my dev machine.  I am trying to deploy to IIS running on a windows Server

the web.config is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath=".\Zimpla.WebApi.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: 0214ca6f-0fd4-4643-92b7-4202aaa1024a-->
```

It has a separate application for the directory and I get the following error

```
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.
```

Every single page I go to in IIS Manager says "there was an error performing this operation"   - filename c:\inetpub\wwwroot\logistics\web.config  Error:

IIS and users have read and execute access to the whole directory.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you installed the [.NetCore Runtime](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0) before hosting your .Net 6.0 Web application? If not, please install it. Restart your site and again try to check for the issue.

This problem occurs because the ApplicationHost.config or Web.config file contains a malformed or unidentified XML element. IIS can't identify the XML elements of the modules that are not installed. For example, IIS URL Rewrite module.

You could fix the error with the steps below.

- Delete the malformed XML element from the ApplicationHost.config or Web.config file.
- Check the unidentified XML elements, and then install the relevant IIS modules.

If you have the HRESULT code(something like 0x8007000d) then you could refer to the document below to check the error cause/ solution for that specific HRESULT code.

Ref: [HTTP Error 500.19 - internal server error when you open an IIS Webpage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/health-diagnostic-performance/http-error-500-19-webpage)

Comment: Thank you :-)   I just assumed that the .net runtime was installed as part of windows update.   installed that and it workds fine.